# how to set the size of the clickable area on an OverlayItem (for Android)

Tags: android

I have an OverlayItem on a map, the overlay is a pushpin icon.  I want to control the size of the clickable area, what I get now is an area that is much larger than my icon.

I was expecting that the system would set the clickable area to be the size of my icon.

Is there a way to set the size of the clickable area?

Thanks,
Frank

I am still wrestling with this problem and would appreciate any help or clues.  I am using the tutorial from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

The map works fine. But the clickable area is much bigger than my Icon.  I tried smaller icons, I tried setting the bounds of the Drawable but no luck. Is there any way that I can control the size of the clickable area around my icon.

My icon is 34 by 20 pixels but it looks as if I can click about 100 pixels away and that would trigger the onTap() callback.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see some code?

Without seeing any code I'm wondering if you are handling the event for the overlay and not for the specific item... but I really can't tell much without taking a look.